# How to run netperf Omni-test with stream direction correctly

Tags: testing, networking

netperf   v2.7.0

When I  test latency use `stream` or `maerts` direction, I doubt my test results are correct.

```
$ netperf -H 172.18.44.3 -p 12345 -l 10 -j -c -C -t omni -- -d steam -k THROUGHPUT,THROUGHPUT_UNITS,MIN_LATENCY,MAX_LATENCY,RT_LATENCY,STDDEV_LATENCY,P50_LATENCY,P90_LATENCY,P99_LATENCY,LOCAL_TRANSPORT_RETRANS,REMOTE_TRANSPORT_RETRANS,LOCAL_CPU_UTIL,REMOTE_CPU_UTIL
OMNI Send TEST from 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0) port 0 AF_INET to 172.18.44.3 () port 0 AF_INET
THROUGHPUT=442.84
THROUGHPUT_UNITS=10^6bits/s
MIN_LATENCY=1
MAX_LATENCY=233127
RT_LATENCY=-1.000
STDDEV_LATENCY=2226.74
P50_LATENCY=3
P90_LATENCY=4
P99_LATENCY=12354
LOCAL_TRANSPORT_RETRANS=292
REMOTE_TRANSPORT_RETRANS=0
LOCAL_CPU_UTIL=7.82
REMOTE_CPU_UTIL=91.48
```

MAX_LATENCY, STDDEV_LATENCY, etc. are very large. This is impossible. So where is the problem? thx all.